# When voip app was killed by iOS in background is there a way to get notified and do some final work?

Tags: ios, multithreading, voip

When voip app (the one implemented according to Apple's voip guide) was killed by iOS in background is there a way to get notified and do some final (clean-up) work ?

I have tried UIApplicationDelegate's method like `applicationWillTerminate`:  `applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:` and `dealloc`. It seems that none of them get called. So I thought it was impossible and Apple's document seems to indicated that.

But then I find skype seems to be able to do that. If iOS fresh starts skype, it will show default.png as well as it's logo png, but when skype is in background, killed by ios and you click it to start it again, it only show default.png. So I think skype must be able to tell the difference between these 2 kills and do some extra work for the latter one, right?

Update:voip app will still be killed when your memory went low, just harder than apps without  background mode set. You need to start a app that use a lot memory, e.g. "Need for Speed", play it for a while, then your voip app will be killed. Trust me, I have tried these many many times.

Thanks!

Qiulang

Answer (score 2):

Apps that get killed by iOS are not informed about this.

There are just purshed from memory even VOIP apps.

Comment: Then how does skype achieves what I described ?

Comment: That was what I had thought till I found skype's "weird" behavior.

Comment: You are right, I did see this. But beware that if you have Skype running there will be an socket open and it will be running in the background. if you kill the app it will start like fresh. I have tried to get iOS the kill the app but it will not since it's a VOIP client.

Comment: Well, for a voip app you do need to have a socket open when you are in background (to accept incoming call). The question is if app won't be informed when is killed how can it do some final clean up work.

Comment: No, voip will still be killed when your memory went low, just harder than normal app. You need to start apps that use a lot memory, e.g. "Need for Speed", play it for a while, then voip app will be killed. Trust me I have tried these many many times.